# WINE installation. Can not find winecfg

Tags: wine

I downloaded and installed "wine-devel-amd64_4.19~eoan_amd64.deb" from https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/eoan/main/binary-amd64/

There is a .wine folder in my home directory. Where is winecfg?

Comment: What do you mean "where is winecfg"?  `winecfg` is an application, you run that on the command line to open up the configuration tool.  It stores all the config changes, etc. into `~/.wine` by default.

Comment: In the directory "/opt/wine-devel/bin" there is only "wine64" and "wine64-preloader".

Comment: I pasted "7z1900-x64.exe" to the "/home/htpc/.wine/drive_c" directory. In the terminal I typed "cd /opt/wine-devel/bin". Next, I typed "./wine64 7z1900-x64.exe". I get a "wine: could not exec wineserver" error.

Comment: You shouldn't be downloading the .deb individually from that URL.  You need to follow the guide from https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu to set up the repo on your system and install.

Answer (score 1):

The version you installed is a 64bit-only flavour or wine. Use the following command for `winecfg`:

```
wine64 winecfg
```

And you should also use `wine64` for launching executables (*rather than `wine` as you did before on 32bit systems*).

See also: https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ